# Best Linux OS for 64GB ram server

Tags: linux

What is the best Linux OS (server) that can make full utilization of a 64GB ram server machine.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Memory utilization is handled by the kernel, which is common to all of the distros. Tuning can differ between the distros, but in my experience it doesn't vary much at all. 64-bit Linux doesn't consider 64GB to be a very large amount, at least with newer kernels, so they all should handle it very, very similarly. Even the Enterprise distros (RHEL, SLES, OUL) which are running older kernels have patches to make sure their memory management is top notch, as they're even more likely than Ubuntu et. al. to run in high-RAM environments.

In the end, the "best 64-bit distro" is whichever Linux distro you like to work with best. The technical differences are slight at best.

Comment: Totally agreed, any distro is just fine so long as it's red hat ;) (kidding!) Seriously though, the kernel will be the same (with some tweaks) between any of the distros. It's a much better idea to look at what the hardware manufacturer supports and use their recommended hardware (for instance, HP and Dell both support and provide drivers for RHEL and Suse).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you're the most familiar with, it'd have to be 64bit, in any case. For example, I would choose [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) because I know the platform and I feel comfortable with the way things are done. [Debian](http://www.debian.org/) would be my second choice if stability was my main concern, but if I was looking for something bleeding edge I'd go with [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/).

They can all make equal (read: full) utilization of 64GB of RAM because they're all Linux and memory limits happen in kernel-space, not user-space.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest for the same is Cent OS 64 bit version you can use :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Cent Os,because The first thing I noticed with Cent Os was a speed increase. The new 2.6.9 kernel, newer packages, and general improvements seem to have boosted performance, especially of the proxy server. On the same hardware, Squid was using less memory and CPU time, and was working faster.The key advantages of CentOS over other linux-type distributions, apart from its free nature, is its rock-solid reliability and the long lifecycle of the product.

Comment: Man, there are RHEL6, CentOS 5 already! CentOS 4 is pretty outdated for now.